# Call 3 functions at the same time. Should Parallel.For be used?

Tags: c#, multithreading

**Problem:**

I'm currently calling 3 functions inside my code, which are executed behind each other which would take some time to finish. So I was wondering if there is a way to call them at the same time, for example using a `Parallel.For` loop.

In case I could use a `Parallel.For` loop, how would I manage to do this? Would this be the right way to use it?

```
Parallel.For(0, 1, i =>
{
    bool check1 = function1(address);
    bool check2 = function2(address);
    bool check3 = function3(address);
});
```

**My current code:**

```
private void check()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
    {
        string address = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

        try
        {
            if (address.Length < 6)
            {
                // Those 3 functions are currently called behind each other
                // Could those be called inside a Parallel.For loop at the same time?
                bool check1 = function1(address);
                bool check2 = function2(address);
                bool check3 = function3(address);
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = "Error";
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only you can answer if your 3 functions can run in parallel.

Comment: Implement each of them async or wrap them with tasks and then await all 3

Comment: A parallel for loop is the wrong approach here - what are you looping over? If you want to run each method in parallel you'll need to use Threading or the TPL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a quick estimation (are you going to get *reasonable gain*) you can try *Parallel Linq* (*PLinq*).

```
bool[] results = new Func<string, bool>[] {function1, function2, function3}
  .AsParallel()
  .AsOrdered() // <- to guarantee function / outcome correspondence
  .Select(f => f(address))
  .ToArray();  

bool check1 = results[0];
bool check2 = results[1];
bool check3 = results[2];
```

Comment: I think you want an `AsOrdered()` in there as well if you want to *guarantee* the correspondence between the `check` variables and the same numbered `function`s

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Nice catch! You are quite right - `.AsOrdered()` should be put, thank you!

Comment: Won't this still run `function1`, `function2`, and `function3` in sequential order?  It sounds to me that he actually wants to execute those at the same time.  I would think that converting them to `Task` and using `Task.WhenAll` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Bradley Uffner: No, It will *not* run the functions in sequential order; we have for that `.AsSequential()`. `AsOrdered()` just ensures that the result (array) will be given in the same order the income (functions): `results[0] ` corresponds to `function1` etc. Converting functions to `Task` can be difficult (we don't know the context in which these functions are used) and may appear useless (no gain, but overhead). That's why I suggest easy to emplement *PLinq* as a touchstone.